# Asp Mvc model binding of array with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Below is a POST url with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

```
POST
http://partner-site.com/api_implementation/hotel_availability

BODY
api_version=4
&hotels=[{"ta_id":97497,"partner_id":"229547","partner_url":"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/229547"},{"ta_id":97832,"partner_id":"id34234","partner_url":"http://partner.com/deeplink/to/id34234"}]
&start_date=2013-07-01
&end_date=2013-07-03
&num_adults=2
&num_rooms=1
&lang=en_US
&currency=USD
&user_country=US
&device_type=d
&query_key=6167a22d1f87d2028bf60a8e5e27afa7_191_1360299600000_2_2

CONTENT TYPE
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

And i have wrote the class that read like

```
public class HotelAvailabilityRequest
{
    public int api_version { get; set; }
    public List<HotelSummary> hotels { get; set; }
    public string start_date { get; set; }
    public string end_date { get; set; }
    public int num_adults { get; set; }
    public int num_rooms { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public string query_key { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string user_country { get; set; }
    public string device_type { get; set; }        
}

public class HotelSummary
{
    public int ta_id { get; set; }
    public string partner_id { get; set; }
    public string partner_url { get; set; }
}
```

When i use the HotelAvailabilityRequest in my ASP MVC method

```
public ActionResult Hotel_Availability(HotelAvailabilityRequest request)
{}
```

I'm getting other parameter like request.api_version, request.device_type except **request.hotels**

I'm getting **request.hotels.Count() equal to zero**.

**How do i get the request.hotel to bind accordingly?**

Comment: Try changing the content-type to `application/json`

Comment: The POST request was made by third party which I have no control. Any other ways?

Comment: You'll have to probably create a custom model binder. http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=584

Comment: This model binder looks promisin http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/701182/A-Custom-Model-Binder-for-Passing-Complex-Objects?msg=4760015#xx4760015xx but i'm getting some error while trying to use it.

Comment: Found this detail explanation of what we can do on ModelBinder http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few round of testing, I resort to manually parsing and deserializing my query string. Since primitive types (int, string like request.api_version) are well captured by the default model binder, my focus is to resolve the complex object type (request.hotels) that is problem.

First, I get the full query string with

```
    Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
    var queryString = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    var queryStringCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
```

Then, I deserialize the query string into the intended object list

```
    var hotelStr = queryStringCollection.Get("hotels");
    var requestHotels = (List<HotelSummary>) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(hotelStr, typeof (List<HotelSummary>));
    request.hotels = requestHotels;
```

Not the best solution but it works. Hope someone workout a better ModelBinder for ASP MVC that resolve complex object type at binding.